# C# UDP Server Client not receiving each others messages?

Tags: c#, server, udp, client

so for my UDP C# chat application, I have a server program which is intended to recieve a response by listening for the client to send it on Port 8001, when it recieves the acknolwedement from the client it is supposed to send a message back to the client. However, though the client and server both say they are listening for each other, the server always immediately reports that it sent the message to IP address 0.0.0.0, so they are not linking, below is the code to the client and server:

Server:

```
const int listenPort = 8001;


    bool done = false;
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);


try
    {
    while (!done)
    {

string text_to_send = satt.Text;
    if (text_to_send.Length == 0)
    {
    done = true;
    }
    else
    {
    byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text_to_send);





try
{

string IPAddress1 = "";
IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
string Hostname = null;
Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
{
if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
IPAddress1 = Convert.ToString(IP);
}
else

{
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
string data_recieved;
byte[] recieve_byte_array;
try
{
while (!done)
{
Console.WriteLine("Looking for attack buddies " + groupEP);
recieve_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
Console.WriteLine("New buddy found at + " + groupEP.ToString());
data_recieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieve_byte_array, 0, recieve_byte_array.Length);
Console.WriteLine(data_recieved);
}
}

catch (Exception n)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Attack information could not be sent. Please make sure your buddies are reachable" + n.ToString());
}
}
}
}
catch (Exception j)
{
Console.WriteLine("Please make sure all needed information is filled out");
}
```

Client:

```
const int listenPort = 8001;


            bool done = false;
            UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
            string data_recieved;
            string searchcount_sent = searchcount.ToString();
            byte[] send_byte_array;
            byte[] recieve_byte_array;
            try
            {
                while (!done)


                {
           string IPAddress1 = "";
           IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
           string Hostname = null;
           Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
           Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
           foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
           {
           if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
             IPAddress1 = Convert.ToString(IP);
              }
              }
            string text_to_send = "Request to connect from: " + IPAddress1;
            if (text_to_send.Length == 0)
            {
            done = true;
             }
            else

            {
                       
          MessageBox.Show("Now listening on port 8001.");
          Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,       SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
          IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse(RecieveIP.Text);
           IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, 8001);
   Console.WriteLine("Now sending out packet to be acknolwedged by lead computer.");

            byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text_to_send);
    Console.WriteLine("Listening for the attack information on port " + listenPort);
    recieve_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
    data_recieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieve_byte_array, 0, recieve_byte_array.Length);


    try
    {
    sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point);
     }
    catch (Exception send_exception)
      {

     Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}", send_exception);
       }
     MessageBox.Show("Listening for attack information.");
```

The two computers are finding each other via arp-a. So wondering why they would not be receiving each others message? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you take a bit of time to reformat your code? The indentation is all over the place at the moment (particularly in the first section) which makes it really hard to read.

Comment: Make sure you do not have duplicate IP in network.  Use Ping and disconnect computer you are pinging and see if you get a response.

Comment: Wow not sure how the crazy indents happend. Fixed now. Yes, there is no response from CMD ping, but when using arp-a the two computers ips do show up to each other. Thanks.

Comment: Does this code look like it should work? Thanks.